# ArrayList class separate from Java main file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two separate files, one named `WonderfulArrayList`, and the other named `ArrayListMain` (I'm experimenting with ArrayLists, and I'm not quite sure what to do) and so I have a method in the WonderfulArrayList file, but the main file cannot see the method, which I have named `booladdData`, which would return true once the data is added to the array list. My WonderfulArrayList file is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WonderfulArrayList{ //implement WonderfulArrayList
     public static int ADDNums;
     public static int index;
     public static int HEADNums;
     public static  ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(15);

     public static boolean booladdData(ArrayList<Integer>arr){
              arr.add(ADDNums);
              return true;
              }
    }
```

As you can see, I have booladdData instantiated with the ArrayList, named `arr`. Now, if you look at my main file:

```
public class ArrayListMain{

  //public ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(15);
  public static void main(String[]args){

          ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(15);
        int MenuNum = 0;
        int ADDNums = 0;
        Object Obj = new Object();

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in); //set up scanner for user input

        while(MenuNum != 7){ //menu loop
              Menu(MenuNum);  
              MenuNum = scanner1.nextInt();

              if(MenuNum == 1){

                 arr.booladdData();
                 }
```

For some reason, even though I know that booladdData is created as public and they're both in the same folder, the main file doesn't have the scope to be able to see booladdData in the separate file.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are all members and methods in `WonderfulArraylist` written as `static`? Is there a specific reason or you just saw some compiling errors and thought that's the right fix?

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `WonderfulArrayList.booladdData(arr)` instead of `arr.booladdData()`. The method `booladdData()` is defined as a class method of your `WonderfulArrayList` class. It's not an instance method of Java's `ArrayList`.

You also might want to read into *object*-oriented programming. Everything in your code is `static`.

Comment: Better yet, take the static off of everything in that class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your type instead of `ArrayList`

```
package com.jbirdvegas.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainClazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // notice I'm creating my type `MyArrayList` instead of `ArrayList` type
        MyArrayList myArrayList = new MyArrayList();
        myArrayList.add("blah");
        System.out.println("My message:" + myArrayList.getSomething());
    }
}

class MyArrayList extends ArrayList {
    public String getSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
My message: something
```